# how to stop tail -f command executed in sub shell

Tags: bash

I tried various steps from http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068My  but I am unable to achieve is how to kill the tail -f command after certain time interval.

my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function strt ()
{
command 1..
command 2..
}

export -f strt
su user -c 'set -e && RUN_Server.sh > server.log && tail -f server.log & pid=$! { sleep 20; kill $pid; } && strt'

exit 0.
```

I am trying to kill the pid of tail -f server.log and proceed to 'strt' which is small function to find if jboss server is started or not.

on executing I get error as

bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `{' .

Comment: Can you run everything in the `-c` argument without the "su" ?  Seems like your subshell should use parentheses instead of curly braces, like `( sleep 20; kill $pid; )`.

Comment: NO buddy, i tried with parentheses. but same error.

Comment: Why use `tail` at all? seems like it would make more sense to just `RUN_Server.sh | tee server.log`.

Comment: Ok. the tee server.log shows the growth of the file that is being written by RUN_Server.log,  but  how do i kill the pid of it. such that with exit code 0 , script proceed to run  "strt"..

Comment: Exit code of the subshell?  Or exit code of the RUN_Server.sh script?

Comment: exit code of subshell. i have to give ctrl+c to kill the subshell.

Comment: So the exit code of `RUN_Server.sh | tee server.log` will be the status of the last command in the pipe (tee), which will presumably always succeed.  If you need a `RUN_Server.sh` failure to show up later you can use `set -o pipefail`?  I'm still not sure of the big picture.  What you're trying to kill is the `RUN_Server.sh` script, right?  Because you wouldn't be able to kill the `tee` but leave the `RUN_Server.sh` running...

Comment: Rob, I appreciate your help. the RUN_Server.sh is a script which start the compiere server and write the log in server.log.  i usually do 'more server.log' to find at the end of file (server started in XX sec). i am trying in script to end the tail -f server.log automatically. Manually i need to give ctrl+c to make subshell exit. after script execute 'strt' to find jboss server is started or not just to verify.. run_server.sh is succeeded withoutany error.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```sh
timeout 20 tail -f server.log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pid=$! { sleep 20 ; kill $pid; }
```

What are you trying to do? Maybe just adding a semicolon before `{` can help?

Comment: No buddy.. that doesnt work.  ALL i m trying to exit the tail after N second. because tail -f server.log will show the continues growth of server.log.  in terminal.. i have to give ctrl+c to kill shell. i am trying that in bash script.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that you `slee`p command won't run until after you kill your `tail`.

The command structure:

```
command1 && command2
```

says to run `command1` and if it exits with an exit code of `0`, then run `command2`. It's equivalent to this:

```
if command1
then
     command2
fi
```

I had a similar situation to this a while ago. I had to start up a Weblogic server, wait until the server started, then do something on the server.

I ended up using [named pipes (Directions)](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash) to do this. I ran the command that started the Weblogic server through this named pipe. I then had another process read the pipe, and when I saw the startup string, I broke out of my loop and continued my program.

The link above should give you complete directions on doing just that.

Comment: Thanks all.  I found a way. [link](https://gist.github.com/2377029) LOG=/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out

sed '/^INFO: Server startup/q' <(tail -n 0 -f $LOG)  .  This will find a word in my server.log and kills it.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying something similar, namely wanted to print out the pid of a process spawned in the background with ampersand (`&`), in a one-liner/single line:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog & ; echo $! 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

... but kept getting the dreaded syntax error, which brought me to this post.

What I failed to realize in my example above, is that the `&` (ampersand) *is also* a command separator/terminator in `bash` - just like the `;` (semicolon) is!! Note:

[BashSheet - Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet)

> - [command] ; [command] [newline]
>     Semi-colons and newlines separate synchronous commands from each other.
> - [command] & [command]
>     A single ampersand terminates an asynchronous command.

So - given that the `&`, which is a command line terminator in `bash`, in my example above is followed by a `;`, which is *also* a command line terminator - `bash` chokes. The answer is simply to remove the semicolon `;`, and let only the ampersand `&` act as a command line separator in the one-liner:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog & echo $! 
[1] 15562
15562
$ May  1 05:39:16 mypc avahi-autoipd(eth0)[23315]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
May  1 06:09:01 mypc CRON[2496]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete)
May  1 06:17:01 mypc CRON[5077]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  1 06:25:01 mypc CRON[7587]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
^C
$ May  1 06:52:01 mypc CRON[15934]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly ))
$ ps -p 15562
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
15562 pts/0    00:00:00 tail
$ kill 15562
$ ps -p 15562
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
[1]+  Terminated              tail -f /var/log/syslog
$ ps -p 15562
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
$
```

... however, in this example, you have to manually kill the spawned process.

To go back to OP problem, I can reconstruct the problem with this command line:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog & pid=$! { sleep 2; kill $pid; } 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

Thinking about this - bash sees `&` as separator, then sees "legal" command `pid=$!`, and then - with the previous "legal" command *unterminated*, sees a curly brace `{` which means a new command group in current shell. So the answer is simply to terminate the `pid=$!` with a semicolon `;`, so the new command group can properly start:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog & pid=$! ; { sleep 2; kill $pid; } 
[1] 20228
May  1 05:39:16 mypc avahi-autoipd(eth0)[23315]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
May  1 06:09:01 mypc CRON[2496]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete)
May  1 06:17:01 mypc CRON[5077]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  1 06:25:01 mypc CRON[7587]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
May  1 06:52:01 mypc CRON[15934]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly ))
$ ps -p 20228
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
[1]+  Terminated              tail -f /var/log/syslog
$
```

Note that the `tail -f` process seems to terminate property, but in my `bash` (version 4.2.8(1)), I have to press Enter in shell, to see the "`[1]+  Terminated ...`" message.

Hope this helps,
Cheers!